# Request.PhysicalApplicationPath equivalent on Window Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I need to convert an asp.net application to window form. but here is the problem
what is the equivalent of **Request.PhysicalApplicationPath**

```
string repFilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\CrystalReports\SampleFile\" + strRepTemp;
```

and FindControl

> `CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("chkItem");`

on Window Form..

any idea?

---

how can i convert this using datagridview on window form

aspx.cs code

```
 foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            string strDrawingID = dataItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[x]["DrawingID"].ToString();
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("chkItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` to get the application's directory. You could just replace `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath` with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)`, but I recommend using `Path.Combine`.

```
string repFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),  @"CrystalReports\SampleFile"),strRepTemp);
```